# Where do I find the character encoding of a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, java, encoding

I'm working with the Smooks framework for Java and having an issue when loading in a Word document. The document is from a non-english source and I need to figure out what the character encoding is. Is there a place in Word 2010 that tells you what encoding the file uses?

Answer (score -1):

Word documents have a specific format, which varies by Word version. There is no separate character encoding declaration. Specifically, Word 2010 uses a special format based on XML, with implied UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question and doesn't cover .doc.